# How do I add my class/jar when the preview tab is throwing ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception, jaspersoft-studio

I have connected an Oracle server with all of my tables to JasperReports through a JDBC connection, and managed to load my tables and fields on the report. I've also added the jdbc8.jar as a classpath to my new Data Adapter, but unfortunately, when I try to preview my new report, I get the following compilation error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleClob cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.6.0.final --- net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignField@47bae235
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JasperSoft Studio to have access to external classes in jar needs these on it's classpath. To add the jar select your project node in Project Explorer and then in menu select:

> Project >> Properties

navigate to "Java Build Path", select tab "Libraries" and then click either:

- "Add JARs" if the jar's are in project folder
- "Add External JARs" if they are not in project folder.

[image: Add jars]

Comment: Hi @Petter, I already added external jars to my project and classes are visible in the nav tree of the project explorer but when I try to compile there are erros about classes are not found, actually I try to add a bean as data set, the class is displayed but when I select the class, the class methods are not read. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @AngelAvila Jaspersoft studio is a bit buggy, try to exit and re enter... that may solve the problem

Comment: yes @Petter, I confirm that, I did not solve the problem, I had to downgrade Jaspersoft Studio from 6.17 to 6.15 )= . Doing this now I can compile without problems

Comment: @Angel thanks for info, yeah studio is still buggy